# Question about disproving if $\exists x_0 : f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ then $\exists x_1 : f(x_1)>g(x_1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> Let $f,g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is monotone increasing and $g$ is monotone decreasing.
>
> Prove/disprove that if $\exists x_0 : f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ then $\exists x_1 : f(x_1)>g(x_1)$.

I think that the easy way to disprove it is if both functions are the same and both are constant.

But I thought of another way and I want to know if it's correct:

Define: $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ which is increasing monotonically and bounded above by $\pi/2$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}+\pi/2$ which is decreasing monotonically and bounded below by $\pi/2$ so for a large enough $x$ (i.e they have the same limit as $x\to \infty$) $f(x)=g(x)$ but we almost always have $g(x)>f(x)$.

**Note: here monotone increasing means: $x\le y\Rightarrow f(x)\le f(y)$ and decreasing: $f(x)\ge f(y)$**

Comment: Take $x_1>x_0$. Then $f(x_0)=g(x_0)\implies f(x_1)>g(x_1)$

Comment: @mathh but what if $f(x)=g(x)=5$?

Comment: Then they're not monotone increasing. Unless you meant non-decreasing.

Comment: @mathh you meant that they're not strictly increasing/decreasing (without equality) no? The question doesn't limit us to strict monotonicity.

Comment: @mathh The convention here depends on the author. "Increasing" frequently means "non-decreasing", and when "increasing" in the strict sense is required, such authors say "strictly increasing".

Comment: @Ian yes here increasing means: $x\le y\Rightarrow f(x)\le f(y)$

Comment: @mathh I added a note for the definitions.

Comment: With this definition, you have already produced the counterexample you need: $f = g \equiv 5$ does it.

Comment: @BaronVT yes I know but I wanted to know if what I did is correct or not.

Comment: For your other example, you have no $x_0$ with $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$. With that condition, $f \equiv g \equiv \text{const}$ is the only counterexample.

Comment: @DanielFischer if both functions have the same limit, doesn't it means that there are infinite $x$ such that: $f(x)=g(x)$?

Comment: No. You have $$\arctan x < \frac{\pi}{2} < e^{-x} +\frac{\pi}{2}$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "$\exists x_0$ with property $P$" means "there exists *at least one* $x_0$ with property $P$". Having an infinite number of such $x_0$ is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = x$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $f(x) = 0$ on the rest of the reals. Let $g(x) = 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.  This gives you a counter-example.